# Question about ad adjoint notation

Tags: lie-algebras

I am absolutely boggled by the notation $ad_x$ as used to discuss the adjoint representation of a Lie Algebra.  A few things I do understand:

I understand what a Lie algebra is in general, including the commutator bracket
I feel like I understand that a homomorphism is any mapping of the form $f(a*b) = f(a) f(b)$.
I feel like I understand that any representation, in general, can be reduced to an adjoint representation by evaluating the representation at zero.

But what totally blows me away is the notation $ad_x$, which is the same as $ad(X)$ (which is equally confusing).  In the wikipedia article on adjoint representations of Lie Algebras, I see statements like:

$$ad_x(y) = [x,y]$$

and people saying that the above equation is a homomorphism.  I completely fail to see how the statement above is a homomorphism.  So:

is $ad_x$ some kind of operator?  Is it a function notation like $f(x)$?  Does $ad_x$ itself have some value that can be inserted (i.e. is it a matrix of some kind)?

Comment: Many authors write $f(x)=\operatorname{ad}(x)$, which makes it perhaps clear.

Answer (score 4):

I think the formula you copied is pretty telling: for any $x$ in your Lie algebra $L$, $ad_x$ is the function 
$$ad_x: L\to L$$
which sends $y\in L$ to $[x,y]\in L$.

It is clear that $ad_x$ is a linear function, so $ad_x\in \operatorname{End}(L)$. Now when we see $\operatorname{End}(L)$ as a Lie algebra, we usually write it as $\mathfrak{gl}(L)$. So we have a function $ad: L\to \mathfrak{gl}(L)$ which sends an element $x\in L$ to the linear map $ad_x\in \mathfrak{gl}(L)$.

Now the magic part is that
$$ad_{[x,y]}=[ad_x,ad_y]$$
which can be rewritten as
$$[[x,y],z] = (ad_x\circ ad_y-ad_y\circ ad_x)(z) = [x,[y,z]]-[y,[x,z]]$$
for all $z\in L$. (And this is just the Jacobi axiom.)

This means that $ad: L\to \mathfrak{gl}(L)$ is actually a Lie algebra morphism. I would guess this is the statement you're referring to in your question.